# Can Istio ignore JWT validation

Tags: istio

We have some spring-boot containers which use oauth2 for authorisation
Unfortunately they were not compiled with jwks

Is it possible to use jwt in istio without configuring jwksUri or jwks?

Answer (score 1):

According to istio documentation about [JWT Rule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/security/jwt/#JWTRule) the `jwksUri` and `jwks` are not required fields for `jwtRule`. However the `issuer` field is required.

Example configuration:

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
  name: "jwt-example"
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "testing@secure.istio.io"
```

This configuration should only check if the issuer of `JWT` matches.

Also from [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/filter/http/jwt_authn/v2alpha/config.proto#config-filter-http-jwt-authn-v2alpha-jwtrequirement) documentation it is mentioned that JWT without verification is possible:

> This message specifies a Jwt requirement. An empty message means JWT verification is not required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The docs also say "If jwksUri isn’t set, make sure the JWT issuer is of url format and url + /.well-known/openid-configuration can be opened in browser" which implies that if its not set it attempts an automatic check. I will go through that envoy bit though thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of Istio 1.5 this is not possible. Envoy will not add a Listener without a valid jwks